# how to access state of checkboxes in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Following the official [ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for controlling form elements, I managed to put together the following with the exception that I'm keeping the checkboxes in a separate function:

I have a function called `CheckBox()` where I keep the checkboxes:

```
function CheckBox(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>Check all that apply:</p>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="a" checked={props.a} onChange={props.handleChange}/>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="b" checked={props.b} onChange={props.handleChange}/>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="c" checked={props.c} onChange={props.handleChange}/>
            </label>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And class App for the state as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fullname: '',
            a: false,
            b: false,
            c: false     
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        const target = e.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
           [name]: value,
        });
        console.log(this.state.a);
        console.log(this.state.fullname);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <label>
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input name="fullname" value={this.state.fullname} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
                <CheckBox a={this.state.a} b={this.state.b} c={this.state.c} />
                <hr/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I kept two console logs in `handleChange()` to check the states. The state for name works fine but I cant seem to get the state of any of the checkboxes to work.

---

What am I doing wrong in the above?

Comment: What is the value of target.value? You might just need to convert that to true or false. Not sure if there is a target.checked

Comment: @TallPaul I am still in the inital learning phase with react and put together the above with the help of the "Handling Multiple Inputs" example in the React Doc. The example is more or less the same to what I'm trying to go for above where there's a checkbox and another kind of input being handled by the same `handleChange()` function.

Comment: The example seems to be using the `target.value` ternary operator approach too so I thought that was the way to go about it.

Comment: As for something to help clean this code which is a fun way to simplify passing data around would be that you can do `<CheckBox {...this.state} />`. This takes all of your values in state and passes them down via [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

You can then also take that same idea and apply it to your event and do `const { name, value } = event.target` That is the same as saying `const name = event.target.name` and `const value = event.target.value`

Comment: That looks like it would work, though Jason seems to have caught your issue.

Comment: @TallPaul That looks way more cleaner indeed. I didn't thought of that approach till now. Thank you. I will read up on using destructuring with react and see if I can use that approach instead.

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer so I can +1 it too. Really nifty way of passing down values in state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `handleChange` function is bound to some arbitrary input field. Your actual checkboxes are entirely separate, and you have not provided your `App` object access to the values in the `Checkbox` object.

You must pass the `handleChange` function to your `Checkbox` object with

```
<CheckBox 
    a={this.state.a} 
    b={this.state.b} 
    c={this.state.c} 
    handleChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was focusing on the wrong part of the code the whole time lol

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer as Jason killed it, but a way to clean up your code is to use [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). I find it is a great way to keep everything a bit more readable and as you continue to use it there are some neat things you can do with it.

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fullname: '',
            a: false,
            b: false,
            c: false     
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const {name, value, checked, type } = e.target;
        const newValue = type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value;

        this.setState({
           [name]: newValue,
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <label>
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input name="fullname" value={this.state.fullname} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
                <CheckBox {...this.state}/>
                <hr/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

For those who don't want to scroll up to my comment above here is the explanation of the two places I used Destructuring to clean up this component.

1. `<CheckBox {...this.state} />.` This takes all of your values in state and passes them down via Destructuring.
2. You can then also take that same idea and apply it to your event and do `const { name, value } = event.target` That is the same as saying `const name = event.target.name` and `const value = event.target.value`
3. You could also use this in the `Checkbox` component so that you didn't need to say `props.a` `function CheckBox({a, b, c, handleChange}){`

Comment: Will definitely do some reading on destructuring as well as coding using destructuring in my react components. +1 Cheers man.